# What Windows IPC method is better for short commands?

Tags: winapi, ipc, command-line-interface

I need one way IPC method for 2 Windows applications (both on the same machine).
Which one is better in case that my applications are **CLI based + windows service**.

P.S. I've implemented message queue in destination process (CLI application) in separate thread. And posting my message from source process (GUI application) via `PostThreadMessage`.
So. When both applications were run from the same user - everything is OK. When I'm running my destination application via Task Scheduler under Local Service user I'm getting 1444 error code (Wrong Thread ID).
Any ideas?

P.P.S.  From MSDN

> This thread must have the SE_TCB_NAME privilege to post a message to a thread that belongs to a process with the same locally unique identifier (LUID) but is in a different desktop. Otherwise, the function fails and returns ERROR_INVALID_THREAD_ID.
>
> This thread must either belong to the same desktop as the calling thread or to a process with the same LUID. Otherwise, the function fails and returns ERROR_INVALID_THREAD_ID.

So. I should determine how to setup `SE_TCB_NAME` to my thread from my source process.

Answer (score 1):

WM_COPYDATA message or custom message code (if you don't plan to transfer text or binary data) would work. WM_COPYDATA message lets you transfer binary data and Windows does copying across process boundaries itself.

In GUI -> CLI application you would need to create an invisible window in CLI process to receive messages (if you want messages to be SENT and not POSTed from the GUI application). If you just POST messages from GUI to CLI, then PostThreadMessage() function would be enough and there's no need for a window.

In CLI -> GUI direction there are no complexities at all as the window is already (usually) present in GUI application.

Comment: Thanks, it is quite interesting solution. I know about WM_COPYDATA but never thought about hidden window...

Answer (score 0):

There is also nice solution - [Message Queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.message_queue) from boost library.